Parse mode in Python Telegram Bot
I wanted it to be automatically copied after sending this message when clicking on context.user_data["code"] So I used `` and parse_mode="MarkdownV2"
await context.bot.send_message(
    chat_id=CHANEL_ID, 
    text= f"{context.user_data['key']}\n\nCode:  `{context.user_data['code']}`\n\nMod:  {context.user_data['mod']}\n\nby: @{update.effective_user.username}",
    parse_mode='MarkdownV2'
    )

But if username of the user has _ like: @Jason_99, I get the following error. how to fix it?
telegram.error.BadRequest: Can't parse entities: can't find end of italic entity at byte offset 53
I tried to apply pars_mode to only part of the text. But I don't know if it is possible or not. I did not find a way

You'll need to clean the username so there are no un-closed markdown entries.
I'd replace _ with - like so:
clean_username = update.effective_user.username.replace('_', '-')

And then use it in your message:
text= f"{context.user_data['key']}\n\nCode:  `{context.user_data['code']}`\n\nMod:  {context.user_data['mod']}\n\nby: @{clean_username}"


The proper way to include a link to a user is to make a markdown link to the user ID:
text=f"Hello user [user-a](tg://user?id=1234)"


Thank you very much. The second way solved the problem

In Addition to 0stone0's answer let me add, that python-telegram-bot comes with built-in functionality to escape text for markup processing: escape_markdown. That way you can use
clean_username = escape_markdown(update.effective_user.username, version=2)

which has two benefits:

the username is not displayed in an altered way, but in the original form
you don't have to manuall replace all characters that need escaping (it's more than just underscores)


Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of python-telegram-bot
